# Do the log index and log term variables in a Raft cluster grow without bounds?

Tags: distributed, biginteger, integer-overflow, raft

In a Raft cluster, each log entry can be considered to have a log index (where in the order of the log this entry occurs) and a log term (which "term" the entry occurred in; each election increments the term).

For example,

[image: raft log example]

Here, the squares represent log entries. The numbers in the squares represent the term of each entry in the log. The position of the square (and the number at the very top) represent the index of each entry of the log.

Do the **log index** and **log term** in a Raft log **grow without bound**?

If no, how do you "reset" these variables?

If yes, do implementations (such as etcd or ZooKeeper) support these growing without bounds, or do they use a fixed sized integer type and assume that you will never overflow those variables?

Comment: BTW, ZooKeeper uses the ZAB protocol; but the question still applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do grow without bound. A `long` type is sufficient to cover the log and term for a long time. Like several hundred thousand years, depending on your throughput.

This is what I use in my systems; and I assume I'll be dead or retired by the time someone has to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks! I should have done the math on this: Given a 64-bit integer, at a billion log entries or elections per second (this is completely infeasible on a network), it'll last you for over half a millennium. (If you increase to a 128-bit int, which is harder but still fixed, it appears you can get a throughput of a quintillion (10 ** 18) ops / s and last for longer than the universe has been around many times over.)